# my old xcode was disappear after i downloaded new version xcode 3.2.4

Tags: xcode

i hav xcode 3.2.2 and when i was downloaded new version and dragged it to Dock  the old one 3.2.2. is get disappeared ..
i dont know whether it hidden or removed ...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It was overwritten at install time. By default XCode is written to `/Developer` If you install another version it will overwrite the old.

To get around this you need to move `/Developer` elsewhere e.g. `/XCode3.2.2`

Answer (score 1):

The old Xcode and SDKs were removed (overwritten).

If you want them back, reinstall the previous set of tools from the dmg.  Move them aside by renaming the /Developer directory.  And then install the new tools.

Answer (score 0):

You can also install the old one into a different directory - there's an option for that in the installer. This way you won't have to uninstall the new one first.

Answer (score 0):

During installing a new version you also can tell the installer to install it elsewhere, by clicking the tiny arrows next to the default folder "/Developer"
[image: develpoer folder]